# DRF Jwt simple get_validated_token is not iterable not iterable after login and sending POST request

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, jwt-simple

`Django Simple-JWT is not iterable => self.get_validated_token(raw_token)

i am getting the following error on get_validated_token I want to save a record that arrives via POST to an api, the user just logged in and I save my accessToken as a cookie in the frontend

I would also like to know the object that returns

```
I would also like to know the object that returns

validated_token = self.get_validated_token(raw_token)
for AuthToken in api_settings.AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES:
 TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

-- Acces Token => eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjkzMDAwNjM5LCJpYXQiOjE2OTMwMDAzMzksImp0aSI6IjUwMDNiZjRlMTZiNjRkZTFhMDg5YjE1MWNlMDIwNzEwIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6N30.aecZdu7OLdFyklbtoeZwBbuBf2LXwuGnyi2B6BuhKuc

authenticate.py

class CustomAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
      def authenticate(self, request):
      header = self.get_header(request)
        
  if  header is None:
      raw_token = request.COOKIES.get(settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE']) or None            
  else:
      raw_token = self.get_raw_token(header)            
      if raw_token is None:            
         return None
    
         print("-- Acces Token => " , raw_token," \n\n" )                
         validated_token = self.get_validated_token(raw_token)      
         enforce_csrf(request)        
         return self.get_user(validated_token), validated_token
    
settings.py      
 
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
  'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
      'App.Apis.authenticate.CustomAuthentication',
   ], 
}
    
MIDDLEWARE = [
  'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', # new
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',    
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
    
SIMPLE_JWT = {
  'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
  'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
  'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
  'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
  'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,
  'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
  'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
  'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
  'AUDIENCE': None,
  'ISSUER': None,
  'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
  'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
  'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
  'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
  'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',
  'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken'),
  'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
  'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',
  'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
  'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
  'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
  # custom
  'AUTH_COOKIE': 'access_token',  # Cookie name. Enables cookies if value is set.
  'AUTH_COOKIE_DOMAIN': None,     # A string like "example.com", or None for standard domain cookie.
  'AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE': True,    # Whether the auth cookies should be secure (https:// only).
  'AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY' : True, # Http only cookie flag.It's not fetch by javascript.
  'AUTH_COOKIE_PATH': '/',        # The path of the auth cookie.
  'AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE': 'None',  # Whether to set the flag restricting cookie leaks on cross-site requests. This can be 'Lax', 'Strict', or None to disable the flag.
}

//FrontEnd 
const handlePost = async e => {   
  let name = "proof"  
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(
      "http://127.0.0.1:2000/apis/crateCategory/",
      {
        name,        
      },
      { withCredentials: true }
    );
    console.log('Res ', res.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error ',error );
  }
}
```

I would like to know what is happening or if the library is not working.
I would also like to know the object that returns